# How to optimize a slow running LINQ query that runs quickly in SQL Server

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query that returns rows (items) based on certain conditions on one of the sub-collection of the row (item). The query I wrote works but performs very poorly in LINQ. However if I run the generated query in SQL Server, it almost instantly returns the desired rows.

My assumption is that the query is slow because of the `OrderByDescending()` that is performed multiple times. Is this correct and how can I improve the performance of this query?

Edit: The goal of this query is to select all Foo objects that have a Bar object
where the price property of the last Baz object is within a lower and upper bound value.

```cs
var query = dbContext.Foos.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(e => e.Bars.Any(p => p.Bazs.OrderByDescending(s => s.BazId).First().Price >= filter.LowerBoundPrice));
query = query.Where(e => e.Bars.Any(p => p.Bazs.OrderByDescending(s => s.BazId).First().Price <= filter.UpperBoundPrice));
```

Edit2: This is the generated SQL query.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Decimal(6,2) = 2000
DECLARE @p1 Decimal(6,2) = 1000
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[FooId]
FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
WHERE (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Bar] AS [t1]
    WHERE (((
        SELECT [t3].[Price]
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[Price]
            FROM [Baz] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[BarId] = [t1].[BarId]
            ORDER BY [t2].[BazId] DESC
            ) AS [t3]
        )) <= @p0) AND ([t1].[FooId] = [t0].[FooId])
    )) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Bar] AS [t4]
    WHERE (((
        SELECT [t6].[Price]
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (1) [t5].[Price]
            FROM [Baz] AS [t5]
            WHERE [t5].[BarId] = [t4].[BarId]
            ORDER BY [t5].[BazId] DESC
            ) AS [t6]
        )) >= @p1) AND ([t4].[FooId] = [t0].[FooId])
    ))
```

Comment: You can use `Any()` instead of `OrderByDescending()` than `First()` like this: `query = query.Where(e => e.Bars.Any(p => p.Bazs.Any(s => s.BazId >= filter.LowerBoundPrice || s.BazId <= filter.UpperBoundPrice)));`

Comment: @SelimYıldız - That would be true if it doesn't matter which Baz has to have a price property between the lower and upper bound but I specifically need to check the last Baz.

Comment: What is the T-SQL generated from that query and what is the one that "runs quickly in SQL Server"? Why are you invoking `AsQueryable`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - I added the generated query to the question. When I execute this query it instantly returns the results. Also I don't think the `AsQueryable` call vs just a where clause on the dbset makes any difference.

Comment: Are you measuring just the query execution time or also the query compilation time? What is quickly and not quickly?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - On the .NET side I am measuring the query execution time + the compilation time, but I doubt that the compilation time is causing the query to run so slowly compared to running the query in SQL server. The difference is about 15 seconds. I have also tried to use a raw SQL query in .NET and it does run faster than the LINQ version (about 4 seconds faster).

Comment: I would suggest using a profiler or PerfView to find out where that time is being taken.